# Meaning of constant $A $ in Maxwell's equation $E = Ae^{-hv/kt}.$

Tags: thermodynamics

In Maxwell's energy distribution law of energy in molecule I found $E = Ae^{-hv/kt}.$ What does $A$ mean in this equation?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Found in which reference?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $E$ in your equation is the energy spectral density. If you divide both sides of the equation with the mean of the distribution (i.e. divide by $\bar{\nu}=kt/h$) you will get:

$$\frac{E(\nu)}{\bar{\nu}} = \frac{A}{\bar{\nu}} e^{-\nu/\bar{\nu}}$$

Then integrate both sides of that equation:

$$A = \frac{E_{total}}{\bar{\nu}} = E_{total}\frac{h}{kt}$$